# Implement Sobel Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, bufferedimage, sobel

I want to implement `Sobel` algorithm.

### First

I get gray data of the input image and put data into `mGrayData`:

```
  BufferedImage mImage, mNewImage;
  for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
            int rgb = mImage.getRGB(j, i);
            int newRgb;
             int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff;
            int b = rgb & 0xff;
            int grayLevel = (r + g + b) / 3;
            int gray = (grayLevel << 16) + (grayLevel << 8) + grayLevel;
            mGrayData[i * mWidth + j] = gray;
        }
    }
```

### Then

I calculate every point's gradient:

```
 int[] gradient = new int[mWidth * mHeight];
    for (int x=1;x<mWidth-1;x++){
        for (int y=1;y<mHeight-1;y++){
            int grayX = getGrayPoint(x+1,y-1)+2*getGrayPoint(x+1,y)+getGrayPoint(x+1,y+1)-
                    (getGrayPoint(x-1,y-1)+2*getGrayPoint(x-1,y)+getGrayPoint(x-1,y+1));

            int grayY = (getGrayPoint(x-1, y+1) + 2*getGrayPoint(x,y+1)+getGrayPoint(x+1,y+1))-
                    (getGrayPoint(x-1,y-1) + 2*getGrayPoint(x,y-1) + getGrayPoint(x+1,y-1));
            gradient[x+y*mWidth] = (int) Math.sqrt(grayX*grayX+grayY*grayY);
        }
    }
```

method `gradient(x,y)`:

```
 private int getGrayPoint(int x,int y){
    return mGrayData[x+y*mWidth];
}
```

### Problem

input image:
[image]

**and after be fitered:**
[image]

Now how can I implement this?

### Edit:

I do not know about how to use gradient data.I try this:

```
   int[] gradient = getGradient();
    int maxGradient = gradient[0];
    for (int i=0;i<gradient.length;i++){
        if (gradient[i]>maxGradient)
            maxGradient = gradient[i];
    }
    float scaleFactor = 255.0f / maxGradient;
    for (int y = 1; y < mHeight - 1; ++y)
        for (int x = 1; x < mWidth - 1; ++x)
            if (Math.round(scaleFactor * gradient[y * mWidth + x]) >= mThreshold)
            {
                mNewImage.setRGB(x, y, 0x000000);
            }else {
                mNewImage.setRGB(x,y,mGrayData[y * mWidth + x]);
            }
    File file = new File("D:\\Documents\\Pictures\\engine3.png");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdir();
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        ImageIO.write(mNewImage, "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I get image:

[image]

Comment: Your next step is to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is too broad, you have to ask a **specific question** or present a problem, not just "What should I do?" or "Is this right?".

Comment: Your question is clear (which is good), but too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson Sorry ! I edited this question

Comment: @CoXier Sorry for being harsh on you. I appreciate your effort to improve your question. Welcome to stackoverflow, just be sure that your next question is well-formed before posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using wrong data for gradient calculation. Your `mGrayData` contains integer value 0xAXXX, where `A` is alpha and `X` is gray value (computed as average of r,g,b).

Instead use

```
mGrayData[i * mWidth + j] = average;
```

**2nd edit:**
Suggestion:

```
private int getGrayPoint(int x,int y){
    return mGrayData[x+y*mWidth] & 0xff;
 }
```

Comment: I edit this question.It still confues me!

Comment: If I use your suggestion ,the color of output image is a little blue

Comment: You mix values for calculations and values for graphical output. You can form 3-byte `gray` in the current way, but use only one byte (gray & 0xff) to find gradient. Otherwise you can get overflows.

Comment: Can you explain it in java?Thans

Comment: see suggestion.